# jqxTree: Changing font color after initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqxwidgets

I have a JSON jqxTree that is being rendered properly (with Label, id, value, etc).  And I have a list of ids that need to be colored differently when the tree get rendered.  I was thinking, that after the tree initializes I should traverse the tree and set the style for each element's id that I have in the list.

The issue I am facing is that from the event initalize() that gets fired, I have no idea how to traverse it and set the style of the elements.

This is what I have so far...

```
var myList = ${myList};
var colorChangeList= ${colorChangeList};

$('#jqxTree').on('initialized', function (event) { 
    alert('initialized:' + event);  
    // put in logic to set labels of id's to blue
    for(Item item : theTree) {
      if(item.id belongsIn(colorChangeList) {
         item.label.color = blue;
      }
    }
});

$('#jqxTree').jqxTree({
    source : myList,
    height : '100%',
    width : '50%'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below url to resolve:
http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/programmatically-changing-font-color-of-labels/

Thanks!!!